# powerline error in command line

Tags: command-line, osx, python

I installed `powerline` by this way:

```
pip install --user powerline-status
pip install --user git+git://github.com/powerline/powerline
```

After that I uninstalled it, but I get this error every time I open a terminal:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: yes. Anyway I would like to uninstall it

Comment: If this happens every time you open the terminal, then something may be wrong with `~/bashrc` or `~/bash_profile`.  Check if `powerline.sh` is called there. If it is, then remove the line and source the bash configuration files with `source ~/bashrc` or `source ~/bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nikolas was saying, this is very likely your `~/.profile` or your `~/.bashrc` files which are calling for `powerline.sh`.

Try to do the following:

1. Locate where `powerline.sh` is called:

   ```
   #> grep "powerline.sh" .bash* .profile
   .bashrc:POWERLINE_BASH=/usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
   .bashrc:    powerline-daemon -q;
   ```

   Here, it is located in the `.bashrc`.
2. Open the file where it is located with a text editor and remove it.

That all, folks.